# Changing xcode package name without creating and importing to new project

Tags: xcode, xcode4

I build an ios application project with a dirty package name, now i want to change this package name but my ios simulator window remains blank on run.  Can someone know how to change package name without doing the primitive imports to new projects. ?

I am using xcode 4.5.2 mountain lion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I change the package name by edit "Bundle identifier" for App "TARGETS"

[image: screenshot]